# DRF Serializer logic to transform data

Tags: reactjs, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, react-table

In a word of introduction - I'm using the react-table library and I want to display in it (if any) all PZItems and no Item or just Item (if there are no PZItems). I decided that it would be the best solution to display the data, as I couldn't otherwise design a serializer without duplicating the data anyway. React-Table  doesn't like data in diffrent form, at least I failed trying to during the tests. I spent the last hours trying to flatten the serializ data which turned out to be a dead end. I was able to write code in JS that transforms serializerdata into the form I need. However, this is not the best solution... Below are simplified models and the rest of the code.

How to write a serializer to match the given form?
&
How to display a table using a react-table with the current data.
The second question is because I'm not sure my approach to the problem is right. However, executing some type of header in the middle of the list in the react-table for an Item that has a PZItem is beyond my abilities.

Models

```
class PZItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='pz_items', verbose_name="Przedmiot", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_available_to_order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

Serializer

```
class TestSerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pzitems = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_pzitems(self, item):
        pzitems = PZItem.objects.filter(item=item).filter(quantity_available_to_order__gt=0)
        return PZItemTestSerializer(
            pzitems,
            many=True,
            context={'request': self.context['request']}
        ).data
```

Serialized data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 62,
        "pzitems": [
            {
                "id": 32,
                "quantity_available_to_order": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 33,
                "quantity_available_to_order": 20
            }
        ],
        "title": "Marchewka",
        "category": 1,

    },
    {
        "id": 63,
        "pzitems": [],
        "title": "Kapusta biała",
        "category": 1,
    }
]
```

Expected serialized data:

```
[
    {
      title: "Marchewka",
      category: 1,
      pzitem_id: 32,
      pzitem_quantity_available_to_order: 20,
    },
    {
      title: "Marchewka",
      category: 1,
      pzitem_id: 33,
      pzitem_quantity_available_to_order: 20,
    },
    {
      title: "Kapusta biała",
      category: 1,
      pzitem_id: null,
      pzitem_quantity_available_to_order: null,
    }
]
```

I wrote a javascript function that converts serialized data I get from serializer to the serialized data it should be.

```
  const TransformData = (data) => {
    data.map((item) => {
      const pzitems = item["pzitems"];
      if (pzitems.length > 0) {
        pzitems.map((pzitem) => {
          newData.push({
            title: item.title,
            category: item.category,
            pzitem_id: pzitem.id,
            pzitem_quantity_available_to_order:
              pzitem.quantity_available_to_order,
          });
        });
      } else {
        newData.push({
          title: item.title,
          category: item.category,
          pzitem_id: null,
          pzitem_quantity_available_to_order: null,
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

I am also sorry if I misspelled the title of the problem. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You have two questions but you are detailing one. Its very confusing principally because you are detailing the business logic between frontend and backend. Where you want to focus? Because like this it will be easy to answer your question.

Comment: @EliasPrado Serializer returns data in bad form. I can't flatten a nested list of pzitems or (as in the example) return just item when there is no pzitem in the pzitems list. I would like to avoid data processing at the front end. I am asking for some tips, because I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Allright, you want to remove the nested dict and join them together right?